# Jquery not working on Phonegap 3.0

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am trying to get phonegap 3.0 to load jquery and nothing happends.

For example this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <input type="button" value="click me" id="myButton" onclick="alert('hello')" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <input type="button" value="click me" id="myButton" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#myButton').click(function(){
                   alert('hello');
               });
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can not for the life of me figure this out. I have the jquery in the correct directory

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: see console and tell us what you can se there(f12 if chrome,ie)

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery code needs to run inside `onDeviceReady` (found in index.js) rather than document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem was specifically, but I updated Xcode and now everything works fine. Additionally, simply putting it inside the onDeviceReady still would not work before I updated Xcode.